# About Silverman's bandwidth selection in SmoothKernelDistribution

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, distributions, estimation

I asked the following question in the site *Cross Validated*: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444320/convergence-of-kernel-density-estimate-as-the-sample-size-grows/444479#444479. It was about estimating the probability density function via a kernel-based method.

For example, let $X\sim\text{Normal}(0,1)$ and let $f_X$ be its probability density function. Let $\hat{f}_X^M$ the kernel density estimate using $M$ realizations. Let 
$$\epsilon=E\left[\|f_X-\hat{f}_X^M\|_\infty\right]$$
be the error, where $E$ is the expectation. The procedure for estimating $\epsilon$ is as follows:

1. Consider a geometric sequence of lengths $M$ (in log-log scale, these points will be at the same distance).
2. For each $M$, generate $M$ realizations for constructing $\hat{f}_X^M$.
3. Compute $\|f_X-\hat{f}_X^M\|_\infty$ for all lengths $M$ (the infinity norm is approximated by discretizing the domain).
4. Repeat steps 1-3 several times, say 10 times, and compute the average to estimate $\epsilon$. Compute sample quantiles to derive an estimated $90\%$ confidence interval for $\|f_X-\hat{f}_X^M\|_\infty$.

Using the built-in function `SmoothKernelDistribution` with no specified option for step 2, I observed that the error $\epsilon$ goes down with $M$ until a certain length $M_0$, from which $\epsilon$ stabilizes:

[image]

It seems that the bandwidth selected is not sufficiently small, which produces bias (stabilization of the error) and small variance (more narrow confidence intervals) when $M$ grows. According to the documentation, `SmoothKernelDistribution` employs Silverman's rule with Gaussian kernel by default.

I implemented Silverman's rule myself with bandwidth choice $1.06\times\hat{\sigma}_X\times M^{-1/5}$, see the answer from *Cross Validated*. In such case, the error tends to 0 as $M$ grows with no problem:

[image]

If the bandwidth selection is $0.9\times\min\{\hat{\sigma}_X,\frac{\text{IQR}}{1.34}\}\times M^{-1/5}$, the error also tends to 0 with $M$:

[image]

Notice also that, in these last two cases, the error attained is smaller and the confidence interval has a similar width for every $M$.

I cannot post the code because it is part of a work. I just want to know which is the bandwidth selected by `SmoothKernelDistribution` (to know if I can use this function in the future), or if you have experienced any problems with this function as the sample size grows.

Comment: What do you mean by "not sufficiently small" ? If you are estimating non-normal distributions, then it usually isn't small enough but you don't mention that in your question.

Comment: Showing your code (a minimal working example) would be helpful.

Comment: The question has been edited with more information.

Comment: Thanks.  I've edited my answer.  Rather than dealing with the error ($\epsilon$) which you don't/can't show, it's more direct to look at the resulting bandwidth for large samples.  You should report the issue to Wolfram, Inc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Silverman rule is $0.9 \min({\hat{\sigma},IQR/1.34})n^{-1/5}$ and the rule $1.06\hat{\sigma} n^{-1/5}$ is the rule that minimizes the mean integrated square error when the underlying distribution is normal.

The default for `SmoothKernelDistribution` is to use the Silverman rule.  That bandwidth (in *Mathematica* code) is

```
0.9*Min[StandardDeviation[x], InterquartileRange[x, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]/1.34]*n^(-1/5)
```

However, it appears that for large sample sizes that rule is not used.  What it uses for sample sizes somewhat larger than 100,000 is $0.09 \hat{\sigma}$ which remains relatively constant.  Here is a check on what bandwidth `SmoothKernelDistribution` actually uses for various sample sizes:

```
SeedRandom[12345]
Do[x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n];
 (* Expected bandwidth *)
 bw = 0.9*Min[StandardDeviation[x], InterquartileRange[x, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]/1.34]*n^(-1/5);
 (* Bandwidth for large sample sizes *)
 bwSD = 0.09 StandardDeviation[x];
 Print[{n, SmoothKernelDistribution[x][[2, 3]], 
   SmoothKernelDistribution[x, bw][[2, 3]],
   bw, bwSD}],
 {n, {50, 100, 500, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 110000, 200000, 1000000, 2000000}}]

(* {50,0.377071,0.377071,0.377071,0.0824551}
{100,0.36585,0.36585,0.36585,0.0918974}
{500,0.251404,0.251404,0.251404,0.0888302}
{5000,0.163237,0.163237,0.163237,0.0896631}
{10000,0.143387,0.143387,0.143387,0.0904713}
{50000,0.103388,0.103388,0.103388,0.0900045}
{100000,0.0895679,0.0895679,0.0895679,0.0895679}
{110000,0.0903596,0.0886534,0.0886534,0.0903596}
{200000,0.0901368,0.0784686,0.0784686,0.0901368}
{1000000,0.0899489,0.0567539,0.0567539,0.0899489}
{2000000,0.0900067,0.0494389,0.0494389,0.0900067} *)
```

So after the sample size reaches 100,000 the bandwidth appears to level off and `SmoothKernelDistribution` uses $0.09*\hat{\sigma}$.  For what you're doing it would seem that you'd want to set the bandwidth explicitly with

```
bw = 0.9*Min[StandardDeviation[x], InterquartileRange[x, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]/1.34]*n^(-1/5)
SmoothKernelDistribution[x, bw]
```

You might want to report this issue to Wolfram, Inc.

****Note that the documentation for version 12.0 states that the default option for `InterquartileRange` is `{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}` but it appears to be `{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}`.  I'll open a ticket on that.  (This has to do with the zillion ways one can estimate a quantile from a finite sample.)

Comment: Your answer is the key. I estimated the mean error and the confidence interval using as bandwidth $0.9\min\{\hat{\sigma}_X,\text{IQR}/1.34\}M^{-1/5}$ when $M\leq 100,000$, and $0.09\hat{\sigma}_X$ when $M>100,000$, and I obtained the corresponding plot to ```SmoothKernelDistribution``` (and also ```KernelMixtureDistribution```) with no options: stabilization of the error and narrow confidence interval for large $M$. So the conclusion is that, for large sample size, the built-in functions fix the bandwidth as $0.09\hat{\sigma}_X$ and the estimates are not improved anymore. Thank you.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that the same issue occurs when the sample size is large for any other built-in option of kernel and bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  FYI:  I've submitted a ticket to Wolfram, Inc. on this issue.